# Delete element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to simply delete the closest li.

It works if I simply do: `<li><a id="delete-hello">Teste</a></li>`

**There is no errors in the console.** *The problem is* that my `li` is generated then the user does something (in this case when clicks a button)
Because of that the method is never triggered and li never dissapears.

How my `$("a[id^='delete-']").click(function()` can run after the li is generated?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //delete testCase row when click delete button
  $("a[id^='delete-']").click(function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
  });

  var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Add test case(s)',
      action: function() {
        var testCaseName;
        var data = table.rows({
          selected: true
        }).data();
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
          console.log(value[1]);
          testCaseName = value[1];
          $('#testCaseList').append('<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between">' + testCaseName + '<a class="action-icon" id="delete-' + testCaseName + '" name="' + testCaseName + '"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></li>')
        });
      }
    }]
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul id="testCaseList" class="list-group"></ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Since your elements are added to the DOM dynamically you need to use the event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead :

```
$("body").on('click', "a[id^='delete-']", function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: lol that was fast. Is this that easy? I've been stuck for hours.Can you explain please?

Comment: On dynamically generated, or numerous elements, it's best to put one event handler on a parent element, rather than each element having their own. This also allows your usage too.

Comment: **omg that works perfectly.** never knew of this.